# Problems with query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

I had two queries - one that selects `group_id` by knowing the `post_id`, and one that checks that user is in that group. I tried to optimize them - put them together, but it now throws an error...

```
SELECT COUNT(bio_community_group_members.id) AS count
FROM `bio_community_group_members`
JOIN `bio_community_posts`
    ON (`bio_community_posts`.`id` = `180`)
WHERE `bio_community_group_members`.`group_id` = 'bio_community_posts.group_id'
    AND `bio_community_posts`.`user_id` = '34'
```

It says:

> Unknown column '180' in 'on clause'.

Problem: I have that entry!

Table structure:

`bio_community_posts`:

- `id`,
- `user_id`,
- `group_id`,
- other stuff;

`bio_community_group_members`:

- `id`,
- `user_id`,
- `group_id`,
- `status`,
- other stuff;

I need to retrieve `status` from `bio_community_group_members` if it exists. That `count` thing was just because I didn't knew how to start to build my query. :(

Thanks in advice.

**Edit:**

Hmm... now it works..... but any idea how to optimize those two queries and get one that also selects `status`?

```
SELECT `group_id`
FROM `bio_community_posts`
WHERE `id` = 180

SELECT COUNT(id) AS count
FROM `bio_community_group_members`
WHERE `group_id` = 41
  AND `user_id` = '34'
```

**Edit #2:**

This is what I was looking for:

```
SELECT `bio_community_group_members`.`status`
FROM `bio_community_group_members`
JOIN `bio_community_posts` ON `bio_community_posts`.`group_id` = `bio_community_group_members`.`group_id`
WHERE `bio_community_group_members`.`group_id` = 41
  AND `bio_community_group_members`.`user_id` = '34'
  AND `bio_community_posts`.`id` = '180'
GROUP BY `bio_community_group_members`.`status`
```

Thanks! :)

**Edit #3:**

I guess that i need something like this...

```
SELECT `bio_community_group_members`.`status`
FROM `bio_community_group_members`
JOIN `bio_community_posts` ON `bio_community_posts`.`group_id` = `bio_community_group_members.group_id`
WHERE `bio_community_posts`.`id` = '180'
AND `bio_community_posts`.`user_id` = '34'
```

But:

> [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'bio_community_group_members.group_id' in 'on clause'.

**Edit #4:**

Just found a bug in the query. Here is the ultimate solution:

```
SELECT `bio_community_group_members`.`status`
FROM `bio_community_group_members`
JOIN `bio_community_posts` ON `bio_community_posts`.`group_id` = `bio_community_group_members`.`group_id`
WHERE `bio_community_posts`.`id` = '180'
AND `bio_community_posts`.`user_id` = '34'
```

Comment: Remove back ticks. Example: id = 180.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the back-quotes(?) on 180, I think you meant '180'? Also remove single-quotes around the other column name, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(bio_community_group_members.id) AS count
FROM `bio_community_group_members`
JOIN `bio_community_posts`
    ON (`bio_community_posts`.`id` = '180') -- Replaced back- with single-quotes.
WHERE `bio_community_group_members`.`group_id` = `bio_community_posts.group_id` -- Replaced single- with back-quotes.
    AND `bio_community_posts`.`user_id` = '34'
```

**Edit after OP edit:**

I'm not exactly sure what kind of optimization you are looking for, but I'm guessing it's something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS count, status
FROM `bio_community_group_members`
JOIN `bio_community_posts` ON `bio_community_posts`.`group_id` = `bio_community_group_members`.`group_id`
WHERE `bio_community_group_members`.`group_id` = 41
  AND `bio_community_group_members`.`user_id` = '34'
  AND `bio_community_posts`.`id` = '180'
GROUP BY `bio_community_group_members`.`status`
```

**Edit after comments:**
Fixed your edit 3:

```
SELECT `bio_community_group_members`.`status`
FROM `bio_community_group_members`
JOIN `bio_community_posts` ON `bio_community_posts`.`group_id` = `bio_community_group_members`.`group_id`
WHERE `bio_community_posts`.`id` = '180'
AND `bio_community_posts`.`user_id` = '34'
```

Comment: Hmm... damn. Not exactly. I need to know user status by knowing only `user_id` and `post_id`. Is it possible with only one query?

Comment: I need to get access level (called `status`) for user in that group. Post can be under one group and relationships are `group_id`. `group_members` have `user_id`, `group_id` and `status` I need to get. You example returns a lot of statuses. :( I need to get only one for that user! And I know `post_id` and `user_id`.

Comment: @daGrevis Ok, your last edit only had a syntax error, see my fix.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ` arround 180

```
 ON (`bio_community_posts`.`id` = 180)
```